# How to access PostgreSQL database data from an Android App?

Tags: android, database, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am making an app which requires a database, so I want to use PostgreSQL from Google Cloud Platform, I did not find any tutorials helping me to do that, How to access the data? a link at [Can i use PostgreSQL or mySQL in android App development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23298590/can-i-use-postgresql-or-mysql-in-android-app-development)
 no longer works or outdated, found the [REST API documentation for Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/admin-api/v1beta4/)  but unable to understand if these APIs are just to access DATABASE or the data inside DATABASE?

Comment: Please visit the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23298590/can-i-use-postgresql-or-mysql-in-android-app-development

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can i use PostgreSQL or mySQL in android App development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23298590/can-i-use-postgresql-or-mysql-in-android-app-development)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the accepted answer to the [post suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23299361/11765092) by @JGH, there are a few ways to access data of a DB from an Android App.

The most commonly used way is definitely by communicating to a service hosted on a server that can connect to the DB, and provides endpoints to request any operation (read, write, update, delete).

However, since you specified a direct connection from the Android App to the Cloud SQL instance, the best option would be to try to make it work with the [JDBC](https://www.dev2qa.com/use-jdbc-to-connect-postgresql-database/) connecting to, possibly, a public IP of the Cloud SQL instance. You may find more information in the [Connecting to Cloud SQL from external applications](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-external-app#appaccessIP) documentation.